# SASS - compiling using pyscss removes square brackets

Tags: css, python-3.x, flask, sass, flask-assets

I'm working on a web app developed in flask. It uses SASS which we are compiling and Bundling using the flask_assets library with the following code.

```
from flask_assets import Environment, Bundle

scss = Bundle('sass/main.scss', filters='pyscss', output='all.css', depends=('sass/**/*.scss'))
assets.register('scss_all', scss)
```

Things were working fine until we started using named grid lines as follows

```
display: grid;
grid-template-rows: 5vh 10vh; 
grid-itemplate-columns: [margin-left-start] 3rem [margin-left-end content-start] 80% content-end];
```

complied to all.css as seen on web developer console on google chrome.

```
display: grid;
grid-template-rows: 5vh 10vh;
grid-template-columns: margin-left-start 3rem margin-left-end content-start 80% content-end;
```

As shown above, it appears that pyscss removed the '[]'(square brackets) when compiling. [The documentation](https://pyscss.readthedocs.io/en/latest/syntax.html#deprecated-features) says square brackets were deprecated. 
Any tips to address this? 
Will using the [sass filter](https://webassets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/builtin_filters.html#sass) address this issue? Also can we just directly use this filter by just installing the ruby gem(or should we install a "ruby stack", I've no experience with ruby)?
What about the [libsass-python](https://sass.github.io/libsass-python/)? Will this be a better way forward?
Thanks in advance.